# how to display thumbnails images from an sdcard in an HTC Desire

Tags: android

just a quick question. how do you get thumbnail images from an sdcard on HTC Desire HD. i have this code but it just shows a blank screen and a scroll. the images can be chosen but as i say, you can't see anything.

```
  String [] img = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    if(imageCursor != null && imageCursor.moveToNext()) {
        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
```

Here is the piece of code where its coming from. Any ideas what i can be doing wrong?.. by the way, the working on other devices like the G-1. Thank you.

Comment: nobody has an idea.. or is there anyway i can have specific details for HTC devices. like a folder specific for HTC in my resource or assest folder. it seems they tend to do things differently than other devices.

Comment: check this [link](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-display-thumbnails-of-images.html)..hope it helps